# Как правильно в данном предложении употребляется слово "не( )ограничено"? Слитно или раздельно?

Tags: слитно-раздельно

*Количество кандидатов, участвующих в конкурсе, не ограничено.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Написание НЕ раздельное: *Количество кандидатов, участвующих в конкурсе, **не ограничено.***

Это причастие, а не прилагательное; можно подобрать зависимое слово в Т.п. (не ограничено правилами).

Сравнить: *Оптимисты полагают, что природные ресурсы **неограниченны** (= беспредельны) в своей величине и не могут быть исчерпаны.* [С. П. Капица. Парадоксы роста. Законы развития человечества (2010)]

В этом предложении краткое прилагательное можно заменить синонимом.